# Is it possible to install a hardware key logger in iPhone?

Tags: passwords, iphone

I took my iPhone to a repair shop today to get the broken screen repaired. It was not an Apple shop but typical kiosks you see in shopping malls.

Post the screen install things work fine but I am a bit worried about something: is it possible to somehow put a hardware key logger in the phone?

Comment: If they had physical access theoretically pretty much anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it is possible. In practice, it would be very difficult and costly to do so. Also, I do not know of a key logger chip for iPhones that can be bought, but feel free to correct me in comments. Of course, an iPhone does not have a physical keyboard, so one would need to intercept the SPI bus and interpret the data.

Moreover, what would the repair shop gain from having key loggers installed in random phones? This gain would need to be more profitable than the cost of buying and installing a key logger chip.

Comment: There is no one chip which would be called "a key logger chip for iPhones". What it would be is a chip compatible with SPI and which could record the data to flash or EEPROM, and those certainly exist (assuming the iPhone touch screen uses SPI). You would naturally need to set it up yourself.

Comment: @forest If you have a link to an SPI chip that can be embedded into an iPhone, I'm interested. I could not find any reference to such a chip.

Comment: By "can be embedded", do you simply mean small enough to fit inside? You'd obviously need to connect it yourself, but these things can get exceptionally small.